# Wordpress 'call to undefined function cynic_theme_finder()'

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress problem on my site, the problem is the site is experiencing technical difficulties.

I have this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   cynic_theme_finder() in
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-content/themes/cynic/header.php:2 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(722):
>   require_once() #1
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(671):
>   load_template('/home/cyste3u7/...', true) #2
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php(41):
>   locate_template(Array, true) #3
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-content/themes/cynic/template-modernpage.php(9):
>   get_header() #4
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(78):
>   include('/home/cyste3u7/...') #5
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19):
>   require_once('/home/cyste3u7/...') #6
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/index.php(17):
>   require('/home/cyste3u7/...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   /home/cyste3u7/public_html/wp-content/themes/cynic/header.php on line
>   2

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a new theme and the errors have disappeared, now the error is Stylesheet is missing. any who can assist